# How to export selected row DataGridView to Word Document in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, export

I would like to export value from selected datagridview row to MS Word as normal document format not as table. The code below is working, however is exporting to a table format.
Please help. Thanks!

```
Private Sub BtnWord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnWord.Click
    Try

        'Private Sub BtnWord_Click(ByVal ParcelsDataGridView As DataGridView, ByVal filename As String)
        Dim objWord As Word.Application
        Dim objDoc As Word.Document

        objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = True
        objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

        Dim _RowCount As Integer = ParcelsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim _ColCount As Integer = ParcelsDataGridView.Columns.Count - 1

        Dim ht1 As Word.Table

        ht1 = objDoc.Tables.Add(objDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, _
                                _RowCount + 1, _ColCount + 1)
        ht1.Borders.OutsideColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlack
        ht1.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
        ht1.Borders.InsideColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlack
        ht1.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle

        For i As Integer = 0 To _RowCount
            ht1.Rows.Add()
            For _col As Integer = 0 To _ColCount
                Dim colType As Type = ParcelsDataGridView.Columns(_col).GetType
                If colType.Name = "DataGridViewImageColumn" Then
                    Dim _image As Image = DirectCast(ParcelsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(_col).Value, Image)
                    Clipboard.SetImage(_image)
                    ht1.Cell(i + 1, _col + 1).Range.Paste()
                Else
                    ht1.Cell(i + 1, _col + 1).Range.Text = _
                    ParcelsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(_col).Value.ToString()
                End If
            Next
        Next
        objDoc.SaveAs2("C:/test.docx")



    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a bit of Googling to learn how the Word object model works, especially the `Range` object.

Inserting text is done as follows:

```
Dim r As Word.Range = d.Content
r.InsertAfter("My heading: ")
r.Bold = 1
r.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
r.InsertAfter("my field value")
r.Bold = 0
r.InsertParagraphAfter()
r.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
```

Comment: Hi SSS, thank for answering my question. This is kind of complicated but I will follow your advice. Thanks a lot.